# Why does isotropic radio transmission appear to be better than optical for communications?

Tags: rf, optics

I have a walkie-talkie that supposedly has a range of 5 km in open country, line of sight, that puts out 1 W in all directions.

Now, if I replaced that RF transmitter with a 1 W light source and the receiver with a photodetector whose area was comparable to that of the 10 cm antenna on the RF receiver, would it be just as good?

Obviously I am assuming it would operate in a dark space, but the intercepted energy at that distance would be the same - or would it?

Comment: You need a light source with 1 W output power and you need a photodetector with high sensitivity. There is no photodetector with equal sensitivity to all directions.

Comment: Light and RF are both EM waves so, why should there be a theoretical difference?

Comment: @Andyaka Wavelength/energy, photon vs wave characteristics

Comment: @Andyaka RF mostly interacts with conduction band electrons in an antenna. Light in the visible range (assuming, granted) interacts at the atomic electron shell transition level. Not much similarity to expect.

Comment: @Uwe It can be approximated for the sake of argument

Comment: @DirkBruere have you heard of the Friis transmission equations?

Comment: We can detect RF coherently, light incoherently, so the noise bandwidth difference is gazillion-fold.

Comment: @Andyaka Not heard of the Friis transmission equations. I'll google them

Comment: Compare the sensitivity of the RF reciever in the walkie  to the photodetector that you intend to use .

Comment: A sub-group of amateur radio operators used to pride themselves on how far they could communicate (using Morse Code) with only a couple of watts transmit power.  When ionosphere conditions were right, several thousands of miles were not unheard of.  I challenge anyone to do that with a 1 W un-cohered light source.